# Ajax to post a form and download file in response

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, download

The following javascript is used to submit a webform to be processed and in return either an error is returned or a file is return on success. the script below is posting the form successfully however how can i get change the script to both download the file or show the response.

note that i am receiving the file, but is it not getting downloaded, the file contents are showing on the console.log

Code:

```
    $("#myform").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $(this),
            term = "tesr",
            url = $form.attr('action');

        var data = $('#myform').serialize();
        /* Send the data using post */
        //var posting = $.post(url, data, function(response) { console.log("1"); });

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("data saved")
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR); 
console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        })


    });

    <form name="myform" id="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="/audit_submit"> 
    <input type="submit" id="generate-string"  value="Ok">
    <div id="result">test</div>
```

*UPDATE:

It seems that the Ajax is receiving the file in the error function

this is a print out of console.log(jqXHR);

> {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,
>   setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

here is a print out of responsedata
[image]

Comment: `.fail` perhaps? read jquery documentation for ideas

Comment: see revision above, no file is getting downloaded or error mag showing

Comment: note that i do not expect a fail. i want to show the error response. this is not a ajax error

Comment: add `window.location.href = 'http://url_to_file';` to success function to download a file

Comment: not working.. i do get an error on the console showing the content of the file: Error: Invalid XML: PK

Answer (score 0):

If your response is an byte array, you can use the code mentioned below.

```
var bytes = new Unit8Array(responseData)
var blob = new Blob([bytes],{type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"})
var link= document.createElement('a')
link.href= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
link.download="filename.docx"
link.click()
```

Comment: I am downloading a docx file

Comment: Just replace the type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Comment: thanks, i have replaced, and am able to download the file, bu tit is blank. if i remove var bytes = new Unit8Array(responseData) i can download file, but seems corrupt

Comment: You need to make sure that you are rendering byte array from your server side application, and responseData is a byte array. Can you share the content of your responseData?

Comment: Your response is not a byte array,check your server side implementation so that you can render proper data to make the above solution work.